# How add a customer to an order when getting the customer details from a form

Tags: mysql

I am having trouble adding a customer and their order to an order table once they have checked out.

Here is my SQL for creating the four tables I am using:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Product(
    ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    Description text(65535) NOT NULL,
    Quantity int NOT NULL,
    Photo varchar(255),
    Price float NOT NULL,
    Category varchar(50),
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
) ENGINE=innoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Customer(
    ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    FirstName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    Email varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    PhoneNumber varchar(11) NOT NULL,
    Address varchar(50),
    Town varchar(50),
    County varchar(50),
    PostCode varchar(50),
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
) ENGINE=innoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS OrderTable(
  ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  Date date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (ID),
  TotalPrice float NOT NULL,
  Customer_ID int NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT fk_Order_1
    FOREIGN KEY (Customer_ID)
    REFERENCES coursework_db.Customer (ID)
) ENGINE=innoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS OrderItem(
  ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (ID),
  Product_ID int NOT NULL,
  Order_ID int NOT NULL,
  Quantity int NOT NULL,
  TotalPrice float NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT fk_OrderItem_1
    FOREIGN KEY (Product_ID)
    REFERENCES coursework_db.Product(ID),
  CONSTRAINT fk_OrderItem_2
    FOREIGN KEY (Order_ID)
    REFERENCES coursework_db.OrderTable(ID)
) ENGINE=innoDB;
```

The problem I am having is how to select the customer from the table once they have been added to the database to use as a foreign key in the `OrderTable` table.

At the moment I have the details of the customer stored in local storage which can easily be accessed, but once the customer is added to the database they will get an ID. This is the only way I could think to select a unique customer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert the customer details first. Then get the ID of the newly inserted customer and use it while inserting the order details!

You could use the [LAST_INSERT_ID()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function%5Flast-insert-id) after you insert the user details to the db to get the ID of the customer.

Or if you are using PHP, then:

- if you're using PDO, use [PDO::lastInsertId](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php)
- if you're using Mysqli, use [mysqli::$insert_id](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php)

Hope this helps.